# local histogram equalization

Tags: python, image, numpy, filter, histogram

I am trying to use do some image analysis in python (I have to use python). I need to do both a global and local histogram equalization. The global version works well however the local version, using a 7x7 footprint, gives a very poor result.

This is the global version:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import matplotlib.image as mpimg
   from scipy  import ndimage,misc
   import scipy.io as io
   from scipy.misc import toimage
   import numpy as n
   import pylab as py
   from numpy import *

   mat = io.loadmat('image.mat')
   image=mat['imageD']

   def histeq(im,nbr_bins=256):
     #get image histogram
     imhist,bins = histogram(im.flatten(),nbr_bins,normed=True)
     cdf = imhist.cumsum() #cumulative distribution function
     cdf = 0.6 * cdf / cdf[-1] #normalize
     #use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
     im2 = interp(im.flatten(),bins[:-1],cdf)
     #returns image and cumulative histogram used to map
     return im2.reshape(im.shape), cdf

   im=image
   im2,cdf = histeq(im)
```

To do the local version, I am trying to use a generic filter like so (using the same image as loaded previously):

```
   def func(x):
     cdf=[]
     xhist,bins=histogram(x,256,normed=True)
     cdf = xhist.cumsum() 
     cdf = 0.6 * cdf / cdf[-1] 
     im_out = interp(x,bins[:-1],cdf)
     midval=interp(x[24],bins[:-1],cdf)
     return midval

 print im.shape
 im3=ndimage.filters.generic_filter(im, func,size=im.shape,footprint=n.ones((7,7)))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions/thoughts as to why the second version will not work? I'm really stuck and any comments would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that 7x7=49 and you are using 256 bins.

Comment: I thought about that... i tried using 49, but no great improvement. But I think it should be 256 because the cdf should be the cumulative sum of how many pixels have each brightness value, so binning by pixel value instead of number of pixels make sense (i think?!). Thanks for the input!

Comment: @user3011255: what if you use like `7` bins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_equalize.html) library to perform Global and Local Histogram Equalization. Stealing with pride from the link, below is the snippet. The equalization is done with a disk shaped kernel (or footprint), but you could change this to a square, by setting `kernel = np.ones((N,M))`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage import exposure
import skimage.morphology as morp
from skimage.filters import rank

# Original image
img = img_as_ubyte(data.moon())

# Global equalize
img_global = exposure.equalize_hist(img)

# Local Equalization, disk shape kernel
# Better contrast with disk kernel but could be different
kernel = morp.disk(30)
img_local = rank.equalize(img, selem=kernel)

fig, (ax_img, ax_global, ax_local) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

ax_img.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax_img.set_title('Low contrast image')
ax_img.set_axis_off()

ax_global.imshow(img_global, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax_global.set_title('Global equalization')
ax_global.set_axis_off()

ax_local.imshow(img_local, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax_local.set_title('Local equalization')
ax_local.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

[image: Results of equalization]